# Why can't I resize my windows to be the same width?

Tags: spacemacs, window

When I split windows using `SPC-w /` then my windows are created with different widths. I want them to split in half. I can't resize it by dragging it nor by using the shortcuts.

[image: Preview of my default screen]

I downloaded emacs for MacOS from https://emacsformacosx.com/

I am using GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109))
 of 2019-04-13.

I am on the develop branch of spacemacs on 0.300.0@26.2 (commit 48ffd37594825b2a2f3e6ff09e18460618449da9)

[image: An example of my layout]

Let me know what other information I can supply.

Comment: If you select another window in that frame do the window sizes change to make the focused one larger? If so that might be a clue that you've got a package like golden-ratio (https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el) or zoom (https://github.com/cyrus-and/zoom) "helping you out". That would explain both the non-regular window split and the lack of drag-to-resize.

Comment: ...and you could also check which minor modes are enabled (`C-h m`) to see if zoom/golden-ratio, or any other window-y, minor modes are active. If it is one of those window management packages then the answer will probably lie in the configuration of those packages in spacemacs (which I don't use, but I expect you can customise its package choices).

Comment: It is exactly that, thanks! Do you mind adding your comments as an answer so that I can accept it? I have zoom in the configuration which I will now tinker with.

Comment: Will do. Stand by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The irregular nature of those windows in your images and the lack of being able to manually resize them suggest you may be using a window-management minor mode such as golden-ratio (http://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el) or zoom (http://github.com/cyrus-and/zoom).

Further clues to check:

1. Do the windows resize themselves to make the active window larger if you change the focused window?
2. Check which minor modes are active with `C-h m` and look for window management modes being active.

If it turns out to be one of these modes then the answer will lie in your startup configuration (probably as configured by spacemacs or your personal customisation in this case).